# ruby on rails: why would a javascript/coffeescript asset be missing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I am working inside of the file `places.js.coffee` while looking at the form page of the places controller. For some reason, any changes I make to the CofeeScript file are not reflected in the browser. I have tried restarting the server, running `rake assets:clean` and manually deleting the contents `/tmp/cache/assets/` , and nothing has worked.

I looked at the output from the rails server in the terminal, and I noticed something strange:

```
Started GET "/assets/offers.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-26 09:35:56 -0500
Served asset /offers.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/partners.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-26 09:35:56 -0500
Served asset /partners.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)


Started GET "/assets/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-26 09:35:56 -0500
Served asset /application.js - 304 Not Modified (6ms)
```

`places.js` is nowhere to be found! why is this? How can I fix it?

Comment: I should also add that 'places.css' IS getting called according to the server, so I do not understand why this javascript file is the exception.

Comment: Try modifying application.js - add a new comment or somthing, might trigger sprockets to recompile all js?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file includes this line:

```
//= require places
```

Comment: shouldn't this be included in //= require tree . ? there is still a file present in the browser, it is just no longer updating.